limit the number of instances of a cloud run job
I'm attempting to restrict the number of identical Cloud Run job instances running concurrently to prevent simultaneous writes to BigQuery tables. However, the --parallelism=1 parameter isn't achieving this goal.
--parallelism=1
I was expecting the second execution to wait the first execution to finish before launching

As suggested here if you want to wait for a task with a Cloud Run job to execute another, the best and simpler solution is to use Cloud Workflows.

I appreciate your response. However, I need to integrate my solution into my company's existing Airflow workflow, which triggers Cloud Run jobs. My challenge is that there are specific scenarios where I need to override the variables passed to the Cloud Run job. Is there an Airflow-specific solution for this? Additionally, it's surprising that Cloud Run doesn't offer more granular control over the number of instances for a job
